# result of selection is array and I want to use it to "where in" another selection

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, selection, where-in

I have two tables (t1 & t2):

**t1** (second column is array)

```
name  | code        

ee    | 123, 124, 125

ef    | 121, 123    
______________________
```

**t2**

```
code_id | code_desc

121     | xxxxx        

123     | yyyyyyy      

124     | xxxxxxxx
```

---

if I do this query, all is ok:

**SELECT * FROM t2 where code_id in (121,122)**

but if I do this query I got NULL cell / result

SELECT * FROM t2 where code_id in (**SELECT code FROM t1 where name = ee**)

How can I get from one query all the info from two table?

Here is the code, I cant find a good sql online tool

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (name VARCHAR(200), codes VARCHAR(200));
CREATE TABLE t2 (codes_id VARCHAR(200), codes_desc VARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO t1 (name, codes) VALUES ('ee', '123,124,125');
INSERT INTO t1 (name, codes) VALUES ('ef', '121,124');
INSERT INTO t1 (name, codes) VALUES ('eh', '123,124,125');
INSERT INTO t2 (codes_id, codes_desc) VALUES ('121', 'yyyyyyyyy');
INSERT INTO t2 (codes_id, codes_desc) VALUES ('122', 'xxxxxxxxx');
INSERT INTO t2 (codes_id, codes_desc) VALUES ('123', 'zzzzzzzzzzz');



SELECT * FROM t2 where code_id in (121,122)
SELECT * FROM t2 where code_id in (SELECT codes FROM t1 where name = 'ee')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_in_set` function:

```
select *
from t2
where exists (
        select 1
        from t1
        where name = 'ee'
        and find_in_set(t2.code_id, t1.code) > 0
        )
```

I'll advise you to normalize your table structure though. Because even though the above query is working, it is non-[sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).